# Docker File Error no such file or directory: unknown

Tags: docker, rust

Trying to build a pkt miner image in order to deploy to akash.

Keep getting this error

```
Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "./target/release/packetcrypt": stat ./target/release/packetcrypt: no such file or directory: unknown
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl

RUN apt-get update

RUN curl -y --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

RUN apt install make

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install gcc git 

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN git clone https://github.com/cjdelisle/packetcrypt_rs

ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/packetcrypt_RS

CMD [ "~/", ".cargo/bin/cargo", "build", "--release" ]

CMD [ "./target/release/packetcrypt", "ann", "-p", "pkt1qd5skpmelkwvzy5vppqhafvmx0n5kqy97eglp00", "http://pool.pkteer.com" ]
```

Comment: Why do you run `apt-get update` so many times?  Once is enough.   BTW, `gcc` and `make` are depended on by `build-essential`.   So all you need is one apt-get install line too:  `RUN apt-get install -y build-essential curl git`.   Also, Ubuntu 20.04 has rust packages (as has every release of ubuntu since 16.04) so, you know, `apt-get -y install rustc cargo` and whatever other rust-related packages you need (see [Ubuntu Package Search Results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=rust&searchon=all) )

Answer (score 0):

Your docker file never actually builds the code. CMD is an instruction to run something when the container runs, but you can only put it once.  The second overrides the first.  You should change this:

```
CMD [ "~/", ".cargo/bin/cargo", "build", "--release" ]
```

To

```
RUN ~/.cargo/bin/cargo build --release
```

**However** it's not clear from your question if that will work either.  I don't see how .cargo is being created.